# "Failed to execute script Test" Error when i execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

"Fatal error detected"
"Failed to execute script Test"
These errors occur and the details below are detailed.

pyinstaller-3.5.dev0+5d872d3ee
python-3.7.3
pycham-JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3 x64

I have installed the latest version and reinstalled it again, but the same error occurs.
No matter how hard I look, I don't think anyone has solved a problem.
Thank you have a good day!

```
56 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5.dev0+5d872d3ee
56 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
56 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
60 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Sang-Hyun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Test.spec
61 INFO: UPX is not available.
62 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Sang-Hyun\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\Sang-Hyun\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\venv\\_dllFiles',
 'C:\\Python35\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin',
 'C:\\Users\\Sang-Hyun\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\venv']
62 INFO: checking Analysis
66 INFO: Building because pathex changed
66 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
69 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
71 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2379 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
2381 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\sang-hyun\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
3620 INFO: Caching module hooks...
3624 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Sang-Hyun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Test.py
3963 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
5533 INFO: Loading module hooks...
5533 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
5535 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
5606 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lxml.etree.py"...
5607 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
5608 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
5706 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
5707 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
7307 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-selenium.py"...
7314 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.dom.domreg.py"...
7314 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
7315 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
7960 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
8880 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
8886 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
8890 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
8896 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
22690 INFO: Looking for eggs
22690 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\sang-hyun\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
22690 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
22697 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Sang-Hyun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\build\Test\warn-Test.txt
22755 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Sang-Hyun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\build\Test\xref-Test.html
22784 INFO: checking PYZ
22787 INFO: Building because toc changed
22787 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Sang-Hyun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\build\Test\PYZ-00.pyz
23466 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Sang-Hyun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\build\Test\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
23484 INFO: checking PKG
23485 INFO: Building because toc changed
23485 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
23621 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
23621 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\sang-hyun\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
23622 WARNING: was placed previously at
23623 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\sang-hyun\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
29495 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
29502 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\sang-hyun\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\runw.exe
29503 INFO: checking EXE
29505 INFO: Building because toc changed
29505 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
29508 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Sang-Hyun\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\dist\Test.exe
29645 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: Please add your code, we can't guess your error from build log of Pyinstaller.